# MySQL syntax error - dropping foreign key if exist

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, syntax-error

The following ALTER statement is working fine on my local (xamp), but on my server (Debian), I'm getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'IF EXISTS `foreign_key1`' at line 1
```

This is the query:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP FOREIGN KEY IF EXISTS `foreign_key1`;
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you showed the full code, or at least a larger portion of it.

Comment: Do you expect us to use our psychic abilities to read your mind, or our teleportation skills in order to drop by and see your screen? Which is your preference? While you're waiting, you can entertain yourself by reading [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your development environment is running MariaDB, and your server is running MySQL.

MySQL doesn't support the `IF EXISTS` in an `ALTER TABLE` statement.

That syntax is supported in MariaDB 10.0.

To confirm the version running in each environment, we could execute

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version'
```

MariaDB  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-table/

MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

---

I don't know if this answers the question that was asked... "What is the explanation for the observed behavior?" (Was that the question?)

Comment: Here is a feature request to add DROP FOREIGN KEY IF EXISTS  into MySQL https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5746 but it was closed as Won't Fix

Comment: can not understand why mysql doesn't support IF EXIST when drop foreign key !!!